# Зачем нужен Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

Сразу уточню, что с Django я никогда не работал, но собираюсь изучить.

Вопрос следующий: зачем нужен Django, если можно написать тот же сайт на HTML + CSS? Выглядеть будет так же, но код понятнее.

Comment: Без иронии доходчиво объяснили, спасибо)

Comment: Если бы все сайты были на html + css. Я бы очень хотел посмотреть на тикток например или на инсту )) 
Почитайте вот эту статью https://web-creator.ru/articles/django

Comment: Если вы можете полностью написать сайт на HTML + CSS — значит вам Django не нужен. Но как только вам потребуется выполнять какую-то сложную серверную логику: проверка доступа, регистрация, написание комментариев пользователями, рассылка уведомлений, загрузка файлов и так далее — вам неизбежно придётся писать серверный код на каком-нибудь из языков программирования, и Django это один из вариантов, на котором можно делать это всё просто и быстро

Comment: @CrazyElf Тут ситуация другая. Фронт и бэк енд совсем разные вещи.

Comment: @farkon00 Да я вообще не в теме Django )  Ну там же есть шаблоны какие-нибудь, чтобы просто сайты клепать, без авторизации и прочего? Или нет? )

Comment: @CrazyElf вы каким-нибудь Joomla не перепутали? Django - это бэкэнд-фреймворк для Python, а вы описываете какой-то конструктор сайтов.

Comment: @insolor Да я ж говорю - я вообще не в теме ))  Ок, я вообще про другое, да

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну, стоит хотя бы поверхностно с темой ознакомиться, прежде чем такой пространный коммент писать) Кто-то же может поверить)

Comment: @CrazyElf Я делал проекты на джанго. И без работы с бд и передачи данных из пайтон Django не сильно и полезен. Ведь надо настроить Django правильно, дописывать функции в views и правильно прописывать urls. Так же есть статические файлы. С обычными файлами без джанго немного проще работать. 

Ну из того что я вспомнил может быть совсем капельку полезным это Jinja. Можно for прописывать. А так всё.

Comment: @insolor Ладно, удалю тот комментарий, чтобы народ не путать )

Comment: @farkon00 Ну если человек не использует логику бэка, а только шаблонизатором пользуется, то Django и вовсе не стоит ставить. Можно обойтись шаблонизатором LoDash на клиенте.

Answer (score 3):

Django - это бэкенд. А HTML, CSS - фронтенд. Это полностью разные вещи. И полноценый сайт, не может обойтись только одной из этих вещей.

Фронтенд отвечает за внешний вид сайт, анимации и за выпадающие меню итд. Бэкенд в свою очередь отвечает за работу с бд, авторизацию пользователей и может влиять на фронтенд. То есть если на странице надо подставить что-то(пример: страница профиля, надо подставить имя пользователя и дату рождения. Вы пишите в HTML коде что-то по типу {user_name} и в бэкенде передаёте переменную) вам нужно будет работать с бекэндом. Так же бэкенд отвечает за алгоритмы и поиск на сайте.

Ну и так же админка, в джанго есть встроенная админка. Что означает, что если вы напишете определённый код на джанго. Допустим в блоге, вам не пройдётся дописывать html, джанго перенесёт данные из бд на страницу. И сможет хорошо с ними работать.